# CSS font not changing?

Tags: html, css, web

Code:
**css**

````
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;```
}

*HTML*
```      <h3 class="textupdonut">donuts</h3>
````

The font is not changing for some reason but i also tried other fonts still doesn't work why?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Have you set up that font family? Where are you getting the font from?

Answer (score -3):

try this it will change
.textupdonut{
font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;```
}

*HTML*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).